# Authentic dua for better eyesight

Tags: quran, sunnah, authenticity, dua

As salamualaikum

After researching duas for better eyesight I’ve come across a few pages and videos claiming to recite Verse 22 of Surah Qaf then blowing it on your finger an rubing it on your eyes.
Somehow that doesn’t really sound authentic/ part of the sunnah to me, which is why it would be helpful if someone of knowledge would help me clarify this matter.